# How Can I Edit/Add Data to HasOne Relationship Fields in Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I'm trying to make one BREAD (CRUD) view for two tables in the Voyager package. It is for a better interface for the future site administrator. In the database, I have two tables: `st_categories` and `st_category_lang`. So I've created Categories Bread in which I have `hasOne` relationships fields connected to the `category_id` field from `st_category_lang` table. The problem is that when I'm trying to edit or add data via this Bread the fields from `st_category_lang` table are shown like simple text and aren't editable.

Relationship screenshot:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ8pG.jpg

Edit screenshot:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLaRC.jpg

Add screenshot:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty0Pi.jpg

I've googled and found only one similar theme, from which as I got it's not possible feature in Voyager currently. But in settings, there are options like add/edit/delete. So what's the deal? Can somebody help with this?

**Category model**

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'st_categories';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'ru',
        'ro'
    ];

    public function categoryLang()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('CategoryLang', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any records on your st_category_lang table?

Comment: yes, I have. Actually if I create BelongsTo relationship  in st_category_lang Bread - it's working ok, but not the HasOne in st_categories Bread..